# R spitting out variables after defining function

Tags: r

I am running osx mountain lion and have recently been observing that whenever I define a function in R after hitting enter it spits out random parts of the variables in grey text.

I am running the latest version of R and have tried reinstalling it.

Here's the output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/output.tiff

I don't know why this is happening, does someone have an idea?

Comment: Could you show us the function you defined?

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: it doesn't even have to be a function, just 10 or 20 assingment like a<-0, b<-sample(2,1) etc. and it returns the variable names etc.

Comment: I recognize that this is not a question by the standards of SO, but can we keep it open so that other newbies w/ MountainLion can at least get redirected to Simon's mailing list?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: it doesn't have to be open for others to find it. Closing only prevents people from answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an intermittent bug in the current version of Mac-GUI for R. It is discussed also on the mailing list [R-Sig-Mac](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-mac/12bfeg2d47/phantom-text-in-console-with-r-2-15-2).